# Question of 15.10 end of life

Tags: updates

I have been running Ubuntu 15.10, and have recently moved to 16.04 due to the impending end of life of 15.10.  However, I am having all sorts of issues with 16.04.  If I go back to 15.10, will any updates at all, even security updates still be provided for 15.10?  Or after July rolls around, will everyone need to be on either 14.04 or 16.04 for any updates?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No security updates will be provided, for any other app, it's up to the developers.